# Nohup : command to ignore tracebacks

Tags: nohup

is there a nohup-command which repeat the task if there is a traceback?

I work with python scripts, and if there is an error, I receive this "ERROR Traceback (most recent call last):" (+ additional information). So, at the moment, I reenter the commands for all the files I receive a traceback manually. But if there exists a command which reenter the command automatically, in case of a traceback, I really would appreciate this :)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: More detail on what exactly you're trying to accomplish would help here. Environment, etc. By traceback do you mean a unix command exiting on a signal, or a java process exiting on an unhanded exception? What do you mean by parallel tasks -- something created them in the first place, right?

Answer (score 0):

Read the section on handling exceptions in the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), and this should guide you on how to catch them, and if approriate, re-run.